# focus() not working after axios call in Vue JS

Tags: javascript, vue.js, axios

I have a `form` in `Vue JS` which is submitted via `axios` call and after `axios` I want to focus on a specific `input` element but it is not working properly.

Here is the `input`:

```html
<input type="text" class="form-control mb-2" :id="'txtTazkira' + s.id" 
 @input="setTxtTazkira($event, s.id)" :value="s.tazkira" />
```

The following function is called on form submit:

```js
submitForm() {
  this.form.txtTazkira = this.txtTazkira
  this.form.selectedNotebook = this.selectedNotebook.id
  this.nextSlot = document.getElementById('txtTazkira' + (this.form.slotId + 1))

  axios
    .patch('/Notebook/api/slots/' + this.form.slotId, this.form)
    .then((response) => {
      this.tazkiraSaved = true
      this.fetchSlots()

      this.nextSlot.focus()
      console.log(this.nextSlot)
    })
    .catch((errors) => {
      alert('Unable to save Tazkira, There might be some issues.')
      this.tazkiraSaved = false
    })
},
```

As it can be seen that after axios call I have `this.nextSlot.focus()` which does not set focus to the `input` element. I also tried to execute the following but did not work:

```
this.$nextTick(() => {
    this.nextSlot.focus();
});
```

I also tried the following where I added `:ref="'txtTazkira' + s.id"`:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control mb-2" :id="'txtTazkira' + s.id" 
@input="setTxtTazkira($event, s.id)" :value="s.tazkira" :ref="'txtTazkira' + 
s.id">
```

And then tried the following in the `js` but still not working:

```
var newSlot = 'txtTazkira' + (this.form.slotId + 1);

axios.post(.....)
{
  ...... 
  this.$nextTick(() => {
     this.$refs[newSlot].focus();
   });
}
```

I searched google and found some related discussions but that did not resolve my issue therefore I posted the question here.

Any help is appreciated in advance.

Comment: have you tried defining `this.nextSlot` in axios callback. I have a feeling that this.fetchSlots triggers a DOM update and you may be lossing reference to `nextSlot` after axios request. Also, using refs, as @Asimple wrote is a better approach.

Comment: Why do you add 1 when you declare `var newSlot = 'txtTazkira' + (this.form.slotId + 1);`? (BTW, in this case better use `let` instead of `var`). Another thing - if you do `console.log(this.$refs)` just before `focus()` - what do you get?

Answer (score 1):

I started creating a test component in my Vue CLI sandbox app before the first answer was posted.  I it wasn't working with

```
this.$refs.input2.$el.focus();
```

but did work when I changed it to

```
this.$refs.input2.focus();
```

Here is the test component:

```
<template>
  <div class="set-focus">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-3">
        <form @submit.prevent="submitForm">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label>Input One</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" ref="input1">
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label>Input Two</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" ref="input2">
          </div>
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    methods: {
      submitForm() {
        console.log('submitForm')
        // Simulate API call
        setTimeout( () => {
          this.$refs.input2.focus();
        }, 2000)
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

The solution for your problem is to use `ref`.

As explained in [documentation](https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/component-template-refs.html):

> Despite the existence of props and events, sometimes you might still
> need to directly access a child component in JavaScript. To achieve
> this you can assign a reference ID to the child component or HTML
> element using the ref attribute.

Have a look at this simple snippet:

```html
<html>
<div id="app">
  <p><input v-model="myvar1" ref="myvar1"></p>
  <p><input v-model="myvar2" ref="myvar2"></p>
  <button @click="doClick(1)">Focus on 1st input</button>
  <button @click="doClick(2)">Focus on 2nd input</button>
</div>

<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2"></script>
<script>
  new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data() {
      return {
        myvar1: '',
        myvar2: '',
      }
    },

    methods: {
      doClick(id) {
        this.$refs['myvar'+id].focus()
      }
    }
  });
</script>
</html>
```

BTW, in your axios call you can use `finally` in order to have code executed independent of the call result:

```
.finally(() => {
  // your focus code here
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ref` instead of trying to get element by id, it would be much easier:

```
<input
    type="text"
    class="form-control mb-2"
    ref="'txtTazkira"
    :value="s.tazkira"
    @input="setTxtTazkira($event, s.id)"
/>
```

and in code:

```
this.$refs.txtTazkira.$el.focus();
```

Also if you set `txtTazkira` ref to array of inputs, `this.$refs.txtTazkira` will also be an array with same indexes.

More about ref [here](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-edge-cases.html#Accessing-Child-Component-Instances-amp-Child-Elements)